# ocLazyload does not load new modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I want dynamically include module into my app module with ocLazyload. My code is

```
 angular.module("one",["oc.lazyLoad"])
    .config(function ($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        modules: [
            {
                name: 'directive',
                files: ['loaded.js']
            }
        ],
            debug: true
    })
})
    .run(function ($ocLazyLoad) { $ocLazyLoad.load('directive')});

angular.module("one").controller("first", function ($scope, $ocLazyLoad) {
});
```

loaded.js

```
   angular.module("directive", []).directive("blank", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<h1>Test</h1>"
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="one">
<div ng-controller="first">
    FOO
    <blank></blank>
</div>
</body>
```

So i can see that loaded.js is loaded successfully. However the module "directive" is not included into dependencies of the "app" module that is why the directive "blank" is not rendered. How i can make ocLazyload to include newly loaded module "directive" into my main module. Does this is supported. Most of examples i have seen used existing module in loaded files.

Comment: if you want to use it right away, you need to use $ocLazyLoad on route resolve function.

Comment: @YOU ok, so with ui-router for instance it should work right ?

Comment: yes, ui-router .state have resolve too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question from the FAQ is probably what you are looking for:
https://oclazyload.readme.io/v1.0/docs/faq

> I lazy-loaded a directive but nothing changed on my page

If the directive was in your DOM before you lazy-loaded its definition, you need to tell Angular that it should parse the DOM to recompile the new directive. To do that you need to use $compile :

```
$ocLazyLoad.load('directive').then(function() {
  $compile(angular.element('body'))($scope);
});
```

You could also use the ocLazyLoad directive, it was mainly written just for this case.